# My 2d maze solver doesn't work for multiple choice

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

I want to write 2d array maze solver and I got it. However, my code doesn't work for when 2d array map has 2 or more solution.

```
public class Mapsolver {

    private int tried = 2;
    private int path = 3;
    private int maze[][];

    public Mapsolver(int maze[][], int destinationcolumn, int destinationrow, int locationcolumn, int locationrow) {
        this.maze = maze;
        traverse(locationrow, locationcolumn, destinationrow, destinationcolumn);
    }

    public boolean valid(int row, int column) {
        boolean result = false;

        if (row >= 0 && row < maze.length && column >= 0 && column < maze[row].length) {
            if (maze[row][column] == 1) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean traverse(int row, int column, int destrow, int destcolumn) {
        boolean done = false;
        if (valid(row, column)) {
            maze[row][column] = tried;

            if (row == destrow && column == destcolumn)
                done = true;

            else {
                done = traverse(row + 1, column, destrow, destcolumn);
                if (!done)
                    done = traverse(row, column + 1, destrow, destcolumn);
                if (!done)
                    done = traverse(row - 1, column, destrow, destcolumn);
                if (!done)
                    done = traverse(row, column - 1, destrow, destcolumn);
            }
            if (done) {
                maze[row][column] = path;
            }
        }
        return done;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "\n";
        for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < maze[row].length; column++)
                result += maze[row][column] + "";
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

If we have one solution it is absolutely work correct. But If we have 2 or more solution it marks all possible ways to solve. However, I don't want to see all solution when I print it. The correct output will be one solution of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you used in order to solve the maze is a [DFS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), and the solution provided will not necessarily be the shortest path to the destination.

The end condition of your recursion ensures that you will only receive one solution. What you think of as multiple solutions is actually a single solution, as can be seen in the following printed example, based on your code (10*10 grid, xx's are walls, the destination is at (6)(3), each maze cell is encapsulated in '|', visited cells are --'s):

[image]

another example:

[image]

and one more:

[image]

The numbered steps in the solution show that the DFS algorithm has provided a very long and winding path to the destination.

Bottom line - you are getting one solution which is a lot longer then you think.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a pointer to the parent vertex for each visited vertex and as soon as you reach the target vertex you stop searching and print the (reversed) path back to the start vertex. But in a so called "perfect" maze, which is nothing else than a spanning tree, there will always be a single path between any two vertices.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.